# Safari Extension: window.open(...) doesn't work sometimes?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I have an injected stylesheet that calls a popup with `window...open()` on two occasions. One when the user clicks an HTML button, and two, when a user clicks on a context menu item. To listen for the context menu item, I need to add a listener on the injected script like so

```
safari.self.addEventListener("message", messageCallBack, false); // Message comes from global.html when context menu item is clicked
```

And the following callback

```
function messageCallBack(msgEvent) {
   ... 
   window.open(...)
   ...
}
```

For some reason, the popup works when the button calls window.open, but NOT when the message callback calls window.open. I'm assuming it maybe have something to do with the window object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is due to restrictions on `window.open` designed to combat pop-up ads. This means it will only work in response to a click event.

To get around this, I would recommend you open the new window from your global page using the `safari.application` API:

```
safari.application.openBrowserWindow();
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = '...';
```

You can also open new tabs with:

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab('foreground').url = '...';
```

To achieve this, you may need to send a message from your injected script to the global page.

Comment: This is actually it! Is it possible to set the properties of the new window as: "scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=540,width=600,resizeable=no,toolbar=no,status=n‌​o"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can set the properties in the same way. But you could try setting them with javascript on the page that loads (injected if necessary). For example `window.resizeTo(600,400)`.